# pandas: IndexError while iterating over DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have this DataFrame and I'm trying to iterate over one of its columns:'Party', and it looks like this:

```
    Year             President            Party      Value
0   1920         Woodrow Wilson      Democratic        NaN       
1   1921      Warren G. Harding      Republican   0.127172        
2   1922      Warren G. Harding      Republican   0.217386
```

My code is as follows:

```
df_Democrat = pd.DataFrame()
df_Republican = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(1,96):
    if table.columns['Party']=='Democratic':
        df_Democrat['Year']= table['Year']
        df_Democrat['Return']= table['Value']
    else:
        similar code for Republicans
```

But I keep getting the following error due to the If statement:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
>   numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid
>   indices.

Would be grateful for your advice.Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you trying to accomplish here?  Do you just want `df_Democrat = table[table['Party']=='Democratic']` and `df_Republican = table[table['Party']=='Republican']`?

Comment: I'm trying to segregate the Values (of returns) based on Republican or Democrat. The aim is to calculate Mean, Median and Variance for each of the 2 groups. Basically trying to create 2 DataFrames- one for Republicans and other for Democrats...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Party': {0: 'Democratic', 1: 'Republican', 2: 'Republican'},
 'President': {0: 'WoodrowWilson', 1: 'WarrenG.Harding', 2: 'WarrenG.Harding'},
 'Value': {0: np.nan, 1: 0.12717200000000001, 2: 0.21738600000000002},
 'Year': {0: 1920, 1: 1921, 2: 1922}})

df
Out[1243]: 
        Party        President     Value  Year
0  Democratic    WoodrowWilson       NaN  1920
1  Republican  WarrenG.Harding  0.127172  1921
2  Republican  WarrenG.Harding  0.217386  1922

#you can do this without a loop using groupby.
df_Democrat = df.rename(columns={'Value':'Return'}).groupby('Party')['Party','Year','Return'].get_group('Democratic')
Out[1238]: 
        Party  Year  Return
0  Democratic  1920     NaN

df_Republican  = df.rename(columns={'Value':'Return'}).groupby('Party')['Party','Year','Return'].get_group('Republican')
Out[1239]: 
        Party  Year    Return
1  Republican  1921  0.127172
2  Republican  1922  0.217386
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting the following error: KeyError: 'Party'

Comment: Did you use my sample dataframe when you got the error?

Comment: No, I directly used the dataframe I already had, which contains 97 entries (list of US Presidents)

Comment: Maybe your column names have extra space or other characters. Run this line before you run the other lines to see what happens? df.columns = ['Party', 'President', 'Value', 'Year']

Comment: Hi, the original time series starts at 1921 and ends at 2015. But the output of the program starts at 1933 and ends at 1976. Can you explain this? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you the desired output

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1920,1921,1922,1923,1924,1925,1926],
    'pres': ['jon doe1','jon doe2','jon doe3','jon doe4','jon doe5','jon doe6','jon doe7'],
    'party': ['dem','repub','dem','repub','dem','repub','repub'],
    'value': [18.61, 17.60, 18.27, 16.18, 16.81, 16.37, 67.07]})

repub = df.loc[df.party == 'repub']
dem = df.loc[df.party == 'dem']
```

Output:

```
   party      pres  value  year
1  repub  jon doe2  17.60  1921
3  repub  jon doe4  16.18  1923
5  repub  jon doe6  16.37  1925
6  repub  jon doe7  67.07  1926
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting the same error with your approach: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: @trulyrural can you try doing `df = df.sort_values(['party'], ascending=False)` and see if you get an output dataframe that is correctly sorted by `party`

Comment: Hi, I tried the line you suggested. Now i'm getting this error: KeyError: 'Party'

Comment: I don't understand why I'm getting this KeyError; the dataframe contains the column 'Party'. But I am unable to access the columns by the titles...

Comment: Here is the output for table.dtypes:Year            int64
President      object
Party          object
Value         float64
dtype: object